# winhttpcertcfg: Granting certificates with for windows service user

Tags: .net, ssl, windows-server-2003, x509certificate

I'm stuck with granting client certificates in Windows Server 2003 with winhttpcertcfg :(

My cert is correctly installed in LOCAL_MACHINE\My keystore and I granted it with winhttpcertcfg.exe. So everything looks good to me:

```
WinHttpCertCfg.exe -l -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "MY_CERT"
```

> Additional accounts and groups with access to the private key include:
>
> > NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
> >
> > BUILTIN\Administrators

But when I try to access MY_CERT in a windows service which is logged on as **local system account** I get the following Exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Log-Details:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [0600] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
>
> System.Net Error: 0 : [0600] AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.
>   System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0600] Socket#21936442::Dispose()
>
> System.Net Error: 0 : [0600] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#24862511:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> System.Net Error: 0 : [0600] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#24862511::EndGetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Everythings works fine if the windows service is logged on as another user. What's the problem with local system account accessing the keystore?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The same issue. I tried command `winhttpcertcfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "MyCert" -a "LOCAL SERVICE"` - no effect.

Comment: I've same error. Did you solve this?